# Communicating with a command line program Java vs C

Tags: java, c, terminal, process, command-line-interface

Lets say I have a command line program. I want to be able to communicate with it from within my java program. I tried the following method:

```
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder(pathToProgramC).start();
    in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
```

I wanted to use in and out to read from the program's output, and to write to its input.

To clarify my exact issue, I wrote two minimal programs, one in Java, and one in C, whose behavior as viewed from the terminal is identical.
Yet the above code works fine when communication with the java version, but waits indefinitely when trying to communicate with the C version. Since the two programs run identically from the command line, how can this be so?

Comment: The term you're after is _inter-process-communication_. What kind of information do you need to exchange? Could you give examples of expected inputs/outputs and the programs involved?

Comment: Perhaps the program is writing to stderr, not stdout. Call [`redirectErrorStream(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream-boolean-) before `start()`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I added more info to the question. To reduce the problem, the info being communicated is just strings like "start" and "end" to show that the programs are able to communicate.

Comment: Even ignoring the question of the implementation of the external program, your example is incomplete.  Much depends on exactly what you do with the Process's streams (including its error stream, which you do not even mention).  It is routine for programs to behave differently when their standard streams are connected to a terminal than when they are connected to pipes.